# Ultmaker Cura 4 has Unreadable Tooltips?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, tooltip

I was using cura in Kubuntu 18.04.02 when I noticed an old tooltip issue that had been around for a while for other applications.

I resolved it by ([inkscape tooltips unreadable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725642/inkscape-tooltips-unreadable))'s answer. I checked the settings and I'm not coloring non-Qt applications, but the tooltips are still messed up for some reason.

Is there a fix for this?
[image: Picture]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Did you install via the AppImage or how? The number of questions they ask is so high that I gave up trying to install the free version :(

Comment: @DKBose Yes, via appimage.